# Get Google Maps v3 to resize height of InfoWindow

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

When I click a marker and the InfoWindow appears, the height does not adjust if the length of the content is longer that the InfoWindow default height (90px).

- I am using text-only, no images.
- I have tried maxWidth.
- I have checked for inherited CSS.
- I have wrapped my content in a div
  and applied my CSS to that, including
  a height.
- I have even tried forcing the
  InfoWindow to resize with jQuery
  using the domready event on the
  InfoWindow.

I only have a few hairs left. Here is my JS:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;

function initialize() {
  geocoder   = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.8801,-87.6272); 
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}

function codeAddress(infotext,address) {
  geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var image  = '/path-to/mapMarker.png';
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: infotext, maxWidth: 200 });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        icon: image
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { 
        infowindow.open(map, marker); 
      });
    }
  });

}

function checkZipcode(reqZip) {

  if ( /[0-9]{5}/.test(reqZip) ) {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'data.aspx?zip=' + reqZip,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(results) {

        $.each(results.products.product, function() {

          var display = "<span id='bubble-marker'><strong>"+this.name+"</strong><br>"+
                        this.address+"<br>"+
                        this.city+", "+this.state+" "+this.zip+"<br>"+
                        this.phone+"</span>";

          var address = this.address+","+
                        this.city+","+
                        this.state+","+
                        this.zip;

          codeAddress(display,address);

        });

      },
      error: function() { $('#information-bar').text('fail'); }
    });

  } else { $('#information-bar').text('Zip codes are five digit numbers.'); }

}

$('#check-zip').click(function() { $('#information-bar').text(''); checkZipcode($('#requested-zipcode').val()); });

initialize();
```

InfoText and Address come from an AJAX query of an XML file. Data is not the issue, as it always comes through correctly. codeAddress() is called after the data has been retrieved and formatted.

HTML in the file:

```
<div id="google_map"> <div id="map_canvas" style="width:279px; height:178px"></div> </div>
```

CSS for my InfoWindow content (no other CSS applies to the map):

```
#bubble-marker{ font-size:11px; line-height:15px; }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having exactly the same problem...

Comment: I couldn't get this fixed either and for the sake of my hair and sanity eventually just reworked what I was trying to do. Would love to know if there's a solution though...

Answer (score 9):

I finally found a working solution for the problem. Is not as flexible as I wished, but it's pretty good. Fundamentally the key point is: don't use a string as window content but instead a DOM node.
This is my code:

```
// this dom node will act as wrapper for our content
var wrapper = document.createElement("div");

// inject markup into the wrapper
wrapper.innerHTML = myMethodToGetMarkup();

// style containing overflow declarations
wrapper.className = "map-popup";

// fixed height only :P
wrapper.style.height = "60px";

// initialize the window using wrapper node     
var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: wrapper});

// open the window
popup.open(map, instance);
```

the following is the CSS declaration:

```
div.map-popup {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

ps: "instance" refers to the current custom subclass of **google.maps.OverlayView** (which I'm extending)

Comment: This is great. You can make the DOM node with `jQuery('<div>...</div>').get(0)`

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap your content with a div and specify it's height: `<div style="height:60px">...</div>`, e.g.

```
 myMarker.setContent('<div style="height:60px">' + txt + '</div>');
```

- In my case it was fairly enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your map canvas is too small. Increase the width/height of your `<div id="map_canvas">` element and you should see larger InfoWindows automatically.

That said, I had the same problem on a site I was building. I solved it by creating a cloned div containing the InfoWindow content, measuring that div's width and height, and then setting the InfoWindow content div to have that measured width and height. Here's my code ported into the middle of your codeAddress function (also note that I removed the `maxWidth: 200` from your InfoWindow declaration):

```
function codeAddress(infotext,address) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            // Create temporary div off to the side, containing infotext:
            var $cloneInfotext = $('<div>' + infotext + '</div>')
                .css({marginLeft: '-9999px', position: 'absolute'})
                .appendTo($('body'));

            // Wrap infotext with a div that has an explicit width and height, 
            // found by measuring the temporary div:
            infotext = '<div style="width: ' + $cloneInfotext.width() + 'px; ' +
                'height: ' + $cloneInfotext.height() + 'px">' + infotext + 
                '</div>';

            // Delete the temporary div:
            $cloneInfotext.remove();

            // Note no maxWidth defined here:
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: infotext }); 
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { 
                infowindow.open(map, marker); 
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap you InfoBox content with DIV with padding-bottom: 30px;

JS:

```
map_info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow();      
var $content = $('<div class="infobox">').html(content);
map_info_window.setContent($content.get(0));
map_info_window.open(map, marker);
```

CSS:

```
.infobox{
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not really an answer (daveoncode's solution to create a DOM node and use it as content is right), but if you need to dynamically change the content once set (e.g. with jQuery) then you can force gmail to resize the infoWindow with:

```
infoWindowLinea.setContent(infoWindowLinea.getContent());
```